# Missing System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' in C:\windows\assembly

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-assembly, white-framework

I've never created any project in C#. I'm trying to figure out how to use White with MS UI Automation library but it's missing a refrenece to System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo. I can't find it in C:\Windows\Assembly even though I've already installed Windows's SDK.
This is a peace of code I try to run:

```
using System;
using White.Core;
using White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems;
using White.Core.Factory;

namespace WhiteTests
{
    public class MyFirst
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
//          System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ("CMD.exe", "/C " + cmd);            
            Application application = Application.Launch ("C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
//          Window window = application.GetWindow ("bar", InitializeOption.NoCache);
        }
    }

}
```

And the error code I got:
Error CS0012: The type 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. (CS0012) (WhiteTests)

What should I do to get the reference to System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo? I'm not a Windows expert.

---

Firstable I forgot to add that I'm using MonoDevelop.
Is there another IDE I can check that? I'm not sure I'll get licence for MS Studio.
I setup the reference and this time I got the problem with System.core:

Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (WhiteTests)

But this library is listed in C:\Windows\assembly catalog.

Comment: Powerful motivation given here to use project templates.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have references to:

```
System
System.Core
```

using this guide:
http://www.deitel.com/books/NET/AddingReferences.pdf

Comment: There was something wrong with my OS. When I reinstalled it. I was able to query GAC and add any dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you need a free MS IDE you can use Visual Studio Express C#...should work fine for developing apps with White.

But, it sounds like your MonoDevelop solution might simply be missing a reference to the System assembly.

In MonoDevelop try going to "Project > Edit References" and click the "Packages" tab.

Scroll down the list and look for the checkbox next to the "System" assembly.  Enable the checkbox if it's currently disabled, and see if you can successfully build.